# .NET C# conversion from UTF 16 LE to UTF 16 BE failing

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-16

I'm trying to convert some strings from UTF 16 LE to UTF 16 BE but it fails to encode the second Chinese character.

Sample string: test馨俞

Code:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sendMsg.Text);
sendMsg.Text = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytes)
```

I've also tried

```
var encode = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true, true);
var messageAsBytes = encode.GetBytes(sendMsg.Text);
var enc = new UnicodeEncoding(true, true, true);
sendMsg.Text = enc.GetString(messageAsBytes);
```

Which results in the following error: Unable to translate bytes [DE][4F] at index 184 from specified code page to Unicode on the line:

```
sendMsg.Text = enc.GetString(messageAsBytes);
```

Thanks.

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense, strings are always encoded in utf-16le in a C# program.  Trying anyway invariably will get your program to fail on a surrogate.  Like U+DE4F.  You'll have to keep it in a byte[].  Or explain what problem you are *really* trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the string to UTF 16 BE. By default strings on Windows / C# are UTF 16 LE. The reason for this is that I want to send this message to a IBM Mainframe.

Comment: You cannot use `sendMsg.Text`.  What alternative there might be is entirely unclear, surely there is one but you don't give us a shot at finding it.  Call IBM support to get help with their product, non-zero odds that it just takes a configuration setting since everybody has this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting this property without any conversion.

```
sendMsg.SetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1201);
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of encoding a string is a byte array, not another string.

Just use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(sendMsg.Text);
```

to encode the string to bytes using the UTF 16 BE encoding.

Then send those bytes to the mainframe.

How you send those bytes to the mainframe may be the topic of another question, but it sounds like you somehow need to present those encoded bytes in a variable of type string. That sounds like a bug in the library you are using. We would need to understand the nature of that library and its possible bug to find a workaround. One option you could try, but it's a shot in the dark, is this:

```
string toSend = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

That will produce a string where each character is the representation of one byte from the encoded string, in UTF 16 BE order. It's length will be double the length of the original string.

Comment: I did attempt this but the .Text property of sendMsg is a string. When I convert it to string the results are treated like so with which the mainframe attempts to hexify the hex string. Ta

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your remark, but this is what you need to convert a string to Big Endian Unicode. Sounds like you question is more about how to send that encoded string (which is a byte array) to the mainframe?

Comment: Sorry mate. Typo there. I meant that I did try that. When I sent the string of hex to them, naturally they saw that as a string. The property .Text doesn't support byte[] I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll give that a spin on Monday when the mainframe guys are back in.

Comment: I got it working by setting this property. Ta.

sendMsg.SetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1201);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should process your input string with the BigEndianUnicode class.

I made this code from the one you provided. It works fine, without error:

```
    String input = "馨俞";
    var messageAsBytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(input);
    input = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(messageAsBytes);
```

If I process "input" with Encoding.Unicode, and print out both byte arrays (the one processed with unicode and the one with big endian), it show the differences:

[image]

So, input is converted to the endian you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll give that a spin on Monday when the mainframe guys are back in.

Comment: I got it working by setting this property. Ta.

sendMsg.SetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, 1201);

Comment: Glad to hear you made it!